# "UndefVarError: `PowerModelsDistribution` not defined" In Julia

Tags: debugging, julia

```
using Markdown
using InteractiveUtils
using PowerModelsDistribution
using Ipopt


function modify_pf_in_IEEE13_bus_system(IEEE_13_bus_system_file_path)
    pmd_path = joinpath(dirname(pathof(PowerModelsDistribution)), "..")
    ipopt_solver = optimizer_with_attributes(Ipopt.Optimizer, "tol"=>1e-6, "print_level"=>0)
    eng = parse_file(IEEE_13_bus_system_file_path; import_all=true)
    eng_timeseries = parse_file(IEEE_13_bus_system_file_path; time_series="daily")
    result = solve_mc_opf(eng, ACPUPowerModel, ipopt_solver)
    return eng
end
print(modify_pf_in_IEEE13_bus_system("******/IEEE 13 Bus Data/IEEE13_Assets.dss"))
```

it generates UndefVarError: `PowerModelsDistribution` not defined IN "pmd_path" line

What's the problem of this code and how to debug it?

Comment: Are you sure everything in the code is exactly as it is here - i.e. no typos in the original code, no difference in the `using` statement, etc.? That line runs fine, and returns the expected path. Copy-pasting the Stacktrace would also help.

Comment: Yes,I am sure about it